# Failed to instantiate module $$UpgradeModule while we run angular 5 in angular 1.x ,at the same time,after I update angualr 5 to 7?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, ngroute, angular-hybrid

Angular 1.x and Angular 5 are running in our project together, I just upgrade Angular 5 to 7, leave the Angular 1.x part. I am trying to make 1.x and 7 work at the same time. That's where I got this problem,

error is :

> Error: Failed to instantiate module $$UpgradeModule due to: [$injector:modulerr]

it says I probably have not installed `ngRoute` in my project, which I checked, I got everything ready to go. Have anyone know what's going on?

```
 <script src="angularJS/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="angularJS/lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>

var app = angular.module('app.mojinshi', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ngResource',
    'ngSanitize',
    'treeControl',
    'oitozero.ngSweetAlert',
    'messageBusModule',
    'toastr',
    'smart-table',
    'ui.select'
]);
```

Comment: **Divide and conquer.** If you’re not sure what the source of the problem is, start removing code a bit at a time until the problem disappears – then add the last part back.

Comment: Did you solve this? What was the solution?

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem? @jess or @Stewart?